# how to use pip in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to use python-telegram-bot. (The version of python is 3)
I installed it using 
`pip install python-telegram-bot`

I run a file with the next code:

```
from telegram import Updater
```

And I get the next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "pyStart.py", line 1, in <module>
from telegram import Updater
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telegram'
```

Even when using `from python-telegram-bot`, I get an error

```
File "pyStart.py", line 1
from python-telegram-bot import Updater
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What causes the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try installing it with pip3:

```
pip3 install python-telegram-bot
```

If that's not working:

```
python3 -m pip install python-telegram-bot
```

If you don't have pip3, you can install it with this command:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install python3-pip -y
```

**Alternatively**, you can build from source:

```
git clone https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot

python setup.py install

git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Comment: How do you know that OP uses Ubuntu?

Comment: I am using ubunto :-)

Comment: `python3 -m pip install python-telegram-bot` worked for me on Debian 10

Answer (score 2):

I think you installed your package in Python2 packages. Try using: `pip3 install python-telegram-bot` for Python 3 environment.